# Liquibase giving syntax error for an included SQL file,which is otherwise correct

Tags: liquibase

I have a change log file,part of which looks like:

```
<include file="ChangeSets/00_SessionAuth.xml"/>
<include file="ChangeSets/01_Legacy_Baseline_V197_ANB.xml" context="legacy"/>
<include file="ChangeSets/02_V198_ANB.xml" context="non-legacy"/>
```

The change set 01_Legacy_Baseline_V197_ANB.xml has 197 sql scripts included,which are part of legacy database.

The change set 02_V198_ANB.xml is defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog  
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext 
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

        <include file="ChangeSets/sql/Dummy_schema/V198_AddColumn.sql"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

When i run the Liquibase update with context as non legacy, i get the following error :

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=SET SCEHMA = Dummy_schema;;BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT;<space>, DRIVER=3.62.56 [Failed SQL: SET SCEHMA = Dummy_schema;
```

The SQL file itself is correct.

I think this is an issue related to end delimiter or splitStatements.

The SQL goes like this:

```
SET SCEHMA = Dummy_schema;

ALTER TABLE T1 ADD COLUMN C1 VARCHAR(35)
               ADD COLUMN C2 INTEGER;

Call Sysproc.admin_cmd ('REORG TABLE dummy_schema.T1');

ALTER TABLE T2 ADD COLUMN CT1 INTEGER; 

Call Sysproc.admin_cmd ('REORG TABLE dummy_schema.T2');
```

We are using DB2 V10.5.

Can someone also provide the list of attributes,we can use with  tag.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think your assertion that

> the SQL file itself is correct

is incorrect. That *is* valid SQL if it was run through the db2 command line application, but it is *not* valid SQL to be sent through a JDBC query, which is what Liquibase does.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Actually it does work, when i use it in the form of Liquibase formatted SQL.

Comment: Hi Steve. I guess the issue is slightly different here.We were able to run this script with Flyway, which would have not been possible if this was not a JDBC compatible SQL.I am not sure if its the issue related to delimiter or split statement.